# Issues creating a virtual HANA table

Tags: python-3.x, hana

I am trying to create a virtual table in HANA based on a remote system table view.

If I run it at the command line using hdbsql

```
hdbsql H00=> create virtual table HanaIndexTable at "SYSRDL#CG_SOURCE"."<NULL>"."dbo"."sysiqvindex"
0 rows affected (overall time 305.661 msec; server time 215.870 msec)
```

I am able to select from HanaIndexTable and get results and see my index.

When I code it in python, I use the following command:

```
cursor.execute("""create virtual table HanaIndexTable1 at SYSRDL#CG_source.\<NULL\>.dbo.sysiqvindex""")
```

I think there is a problem with the NULL. But I see in the output that the escape key is doubled.

```
self = <hdbcli.dbapi.Cursor object at 0x7f02d61f43d0>
operation = 'create virtual table HanaIndexTable1 at SYSRDL#CG_source.\\<NULL\\>.dbo.sysiqvindex'
parameters = None

    def __execute(self, operation, parameters = None):
        # parameters is already checked as None or Tuple type.
>       ret = self.__cursor.execute(operation, parameters=parameters, scrollable=self._scrollable)
E       hdbcli.dbapi.ProgrammingError: (257, 'sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "\\": line 1 col 58 (at pos 58)')

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hdbcli/dbapi.py:69: ProgrammingError
```

I have tried to run the command without the <> but get the following error.

```
hdbcli.dbapi.ProgrammingError: (257, 'sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "NULL": line 1 col 58 (at pos 58)')
```

I have tried upper case, lower case and escaping.  Is what I am trying to do impossible?

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with capitalization between HANA and my remote source. I also needed more escaping rather than less.